# before doing registration check user is signed in or not

Tags: php, authentication, registration

i wanted to check either the user is signed in or not before doing registration. here is my code in below

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
                        $query_ins="insert into scholarship values('$firstname','$lastname','$username','$idnumber','$gender','$dateofbirth','$number','$email','$class','$schoolname','$fund','$reason')";
                    $query3=mysqli_query($con,$query_ins);
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Form is filled we will contact you soon") </script>';
                    }

                    else{
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("You need to login first") </script>';
                    }
            }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: my code is not checking the login status of a user. i want to fill the form after getting login. if a user is not login, the form should display a message to get login first

Comment: @NamraZaheer: What specifically are you asking?  How would you "check the login status" in your application?  What's stopping you from doing that?  What specifically is failing?

Comment: please check my code. it is not properly working. i needed to check the login status before registering but any user can get registered without getting login.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Username var might be existing but empty. try something like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Username']) && $_SESSION['Username']!=''){
    $query_ins="insert into scholarship values('$firstname','$lastname','$username','$idnumber','$gender','$dateofbirth','$number','$email','$class','$schoolname','$fund','$reason')";
    $query3=mysqli_query($con,$query_ins);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Form is filled we will contact you soon") </script>';
}else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("You need to login first") </script>';
}
```

You could also use

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Username']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
```

Comment: In that case we need more of your code to unserstand. Something is faling and it's not the if statement Edit your code above. also check the session var print_r($_SESSION) and see what Username looks like.